# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined when writing command

Tags: typeerror

I am in the process of making my first discord bot, and right now I am in the process of making a "kick" command for my bot. However, whenever I run the "kick" command, it tells me the TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined error. I've tried everything, can someone help me?

My kick command:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'kick',
    description: "This command kicks a member!",
    execute(message, args){
        const target = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(target){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.member.cache.get(target.id);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("User has been kicked");
        }else{
            message.channel.send(`You coudnt kick that member!`);
        }
    }
}
```